# Why are IIFE and regular function behaving differently for creating a read-only variable?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I'm trying to create a read-only variable in javascript by using a IIFE:

```
var foo = {a: 1};
var bar = (function(){
    return $.extend({}, foo); // deep copy with Jquery
})();

console.log(foo); // output: {a: 1}
console.log(bar); // output: {a: 1}

bar.a = 2;
console.log(foo); // output: {a: 1}
console.log(bar); // output: {a: 2}
```

I would expect the output to stay always equal to `{a: 1}`, which is what happens when declaring a function and calling it separately:

```
var foo = {a: 1};
var bar = function(){
    return $.extend({}, foo); // deep copy with Jquery
};

console.log(foo); // output: {a: 1}
console.log(bar()); // output: {a: 1}

bar().a = 2;
console.log(foo); // output: {a: 1}
console.log(bar()); // output: {a: 1}
```

Why the difference in behavior between an Immediately-Invoked Function and a Later-Invoked Function?

Comment: [`bar` in first code give me `Object {}`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qao8n5rp/)

Comment: @Tushar: sorry, a typo in the code - it's fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples are doing completely different things.

In the first example, you're assigning to `bar` the output of the IIFE. If you check `typeof bar`, it should be `object`. You can then mutate it if you want to.

In the second example, you're assigning to `bar` a function that can be invoked later. If you check `typeof bar`, it should be `function`. There is no object there to mutate. Just a function that can take an object as an argument, and produce an output. But that output is going to be the same each time: it's going to be a copy of `foo`.

You're successfully reassigning the value of `.a` in the output of `bar()`, but you're not saving it anywhere so you can read it later. Try converting that last line to `var baz = bar(); baz.a = 2;`. `console.log(baz);` should then be `{a: 2}`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference - if you invoke IIFE twice (I.e. copy whole function twice) you get the same results.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean - redefining the IIFE just after `bar.a = 2` ? I'd like to avoid that (or understand why it doesn't seem necessary in the second example), the variable I'm trying to get as "read only" is `bar`, not `foo` (which indeed isn't changed).

Comment: Aaand I just understood an IIFE can only be called once and the value assigned to the variable is the return value. Thanks for your help and sorry for the confusion !